# How do I update the Time Portion of a custom(dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt) DateTime Cell in the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I Have two columns in the datagridview, `ClockIn` and `ClockOut`. They are datetime columns with the custom format: `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`. I want to update the time portion of the cell but once I click update, the date also changes to current date. How do I keep the date as it is and change the time only?

Here is a preview of what I am talking about:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to calculate the timespan in hours.

```
private void dgv_EmpTimecard_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv_EmpTimecard.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "clockInDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"||dgv_EmpTimecard.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "clockOutDataGridViewTextBoxColumn")
    {               
        TimeSpan workedhours = (Convert.ToDateTime(dgv_EmpTimecard["clockOutDataGridViewTextBoxColumn", e.RowIndex].Value)) - (Convert.ToDateTime(dgv_EmpTimecard["clockInDataGridViewTextBoxColumn", e.RowIndex].Value));
        decimal actworkedhours = Convert.ToDecimal(workedhours.TotalHours) - 1;

        dgv_EmpTimecard["workedHoursDataGridViewTextBoxColumn", e.RowIndex].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(workedhours.TotalHours).ToString("0.000");
        dgv_EmpTimecard["actualWorkedHoursDataGridViewTextBoxColumn", e.RowIndex].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(actworkedhours).ToString("0.000");
    }
}
```

I am using this code to format the two columns.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TARS01
{
    public class TimeColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
        public TimeColumn() : base()
        {
            base.CellTemplate = new CalendarCell1();
        }

        public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
        {
            get
            {
                return base.CellTemplate;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!((value == null)) && !(value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CalendarCell1))))
                {
                    throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell");
                }
                base.CellTemplate = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class CalendarCell1 : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {
        public CalendarCell1()
        {
            this.Style.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
        }
        public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);

            CalendarEditingControl1 ctl = (CalendarEditingControl1)DataGridView.EditingControl;
            if (this.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (!(object.ReferenceEquals(this.Value, DBNull.Value)))
                {
                    if (this.Value != null)
                    {
                        if (this.Value.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                ctl.Value = DateTime.Parse(this.Value.ToString());
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public override System.Type EditType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(CalendarEditingControl1);
            }
        }
        public override System.Type ValueType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(DateTime);
            }
        }
        public override object DefaultNewRowValue
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                //return  DateTime.Parse(this.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    internal class CalendarEditingControl1 : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
    {
        private DataGridView dataGridViewControl;
        private bool valueIsChanged = false;
        private int rowIndexNum;

        public CalendarEditingControl1()
        {
            this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
        }
        public object EditingControlFormattedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Value.ToShortTimeString();
                //return this .Value.Hour.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                if (value is string)
                {
                    this.Value = DateTime.Parse(System.Convert.ToString(value));
                }
            }
        }
        public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return this.Value.ToShortTimeString();
        }
        public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
            this.ShowUpDown = true;
            this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
            this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
        }

        public int EditingControlRowIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return rowIndexNum;
            }
            set
            {
                rowIndexNum = value;
            }
        }

        public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            if (Keys.KeyCode == Keys.Left || Keys.KeyCode == Keys.Up || Keys.KeyCode == Keys.Down || Keys.KeyCode == Keys.Right || Keys.KeyCode == Keys.Home || Keys.KeyCode == Keys.End || Keys.KeyCode == Keys.PageDown || Keys.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
        }

        public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
        {
            get
            {
                return dataGridViewControl;
            }
            set
            {
                dataGridViewControl = value;
            }
        }

        public bool EditingControlValueChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return valueIsChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                valueIsChanged = value;
            }
        }

        public Cursor EditingControlCursor
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Cursor;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnValueChanged(System.EventArgs eventargs)
        {
            valueIsChanged = true;
            this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
            base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
        }
        Cursor IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingPanelCursor;
            }
        }
        private Cursor IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingPanelCursor
        {
            get //throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented."); }
            {
                return base.Cursor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the data that populates the grid coming from?  Is it a viewmodel with a bound collection?  Are you manually modifying the values in the datagrid?

Comment: The values come from the database and I am changing the values by editing the cells in the datagridview.

Comment: Then this is the problem . . . you need to properly bind the values to the data grid, and then use a datetime picker connected to the datetime column in the grid and prevent direct manipulation of the value.

Comment: Is there a way where I can get the date portion from the Dated Column and combine it with the updated time, then assign it back to the two respective columns? Its just that every time I enter the edit mode the date seems to be changing to the current date. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime.Add()` method to add whatever time you need to add. Something like this

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan addingHours = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
dgvTimeAddedColumn[rowNo, columnNo].Value = currentDate.Add(addingHours).ToString();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How do I add it to the existing date without changing it to the current date?

Comment: if you have an existing value and only add an hour, then it should keep the date unchanged (unless the added hour also takes it into the next day).

Comment: @PaulGibson I tried adding the time as suggested above but the date is still changing to current date.

Comment: Try `DateTime.AddHours()` and just add the hours. Infact you can print the resulting DateTime value in a `MessageBox` and see if it's being added correctly.

Comment: @Finweb How are you adding the hours?  Is it manually in the data grid, or are you using DateTime methods?

Comment: @PaulGibson What do you mean by DateTime methods? The hours are already there. I just want to double click on the cell and be able to update the times, thus also updating the WorkedHours and ActualWorkedHours but the dates keep updating too...

Comment: @Finweb, so you are editing the cell values in ClockIn and ClockOut columns. And you are intending to change the workedHours and Actual Worked Hours columns. Which column values are being changed to the current date?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am trying to do. The ClockIn and ClockOut columns. Whenever I enter edit mode that changes to the current date

Comment: In the CellValue Changed event, can you use a `MessageBox.Show()` to print out the two cell values and see if they change there?

Comment: I went used debug to go through the code and also 'Message.Show()' to print the dates and it showed the edited cell changed to the current date.

Comment: Instead of setting the style format for the column, can you instead try to use the formatters of `DateTime.ToString(format)` for setting the `DateTime` format?